# Remote Backup Home Folder on Raspberry to TAR to MAC

Tags: ssh, remote, backup

Can someone please help me out on how to change this to make a tar file of a user home folder on the Raspberry and move it to my MAC desktop

```
ssh pi@xxxx "sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | gzip -" | dd of=~/Desktop/pibackup.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

From the MAC start a ssh session. I assume `sudo` on the RasPi is not asking for a password.

```
ssh pi@xxxx sudo tar -czf - -V "Backup of the home folder from myuser" -C /home/myuser/ ./ | dd of=~/Desktop/myuser_backup.tar.gz bs=1M
```

The options for tar mean: `-c` create a tar archive, `z` create a gziped archive. `f` is the archive name, here with `-` it is send to standard output so it can be piped to `dd` on the MAC, `-V` is a description stored in the archive, `-C` is the directory to start with the backup, `./` is the directory with subdirectories to backup.

This gziped tar archive is piped to `dd` on the MAC and its output file is specfied with `of=`. `bs=1M` is to increase the block size to 1 megabyte for transfer over the network to increase performance.